# Dependencia xmlns: xxx no recogé la clase

Tags: xamarin.forms, xaml, sdk, nuget, arcgis

Estoy creando un proyecto con Xamarin.forms de tipo Shared. Mi desarrollo se esta haciendo en visual studio 2019 para Mac, y como no hay posibilidad de utilizar una plantilla, como si se hace en Windows, estoy creando un Mapa con Esri -> ArcGisRuntime a pelo.

C# y los archivos xaml son nuevos para mi, y no entiendo un problema que tengo al recoger una clase sobre una dependencia.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mapa"
           xmlns:esriUI="clr-namespace:Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms"
           x:Class="mapa.MainPage">
    <Grid>
       <esriUI:MapView x:Name="MyMapView"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Error que me muestra]